# How do i return Null value of Case statement into Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

column`Elites.HasInsurance` is :

```
HasInsurance

   true
   true
   true
```

I will grouping this column by this command :

```
Select CASE WHEN e.HasInsurance=1 THEN N'YES'  ELSE N'NO' END AS HasInsurance, COUNT(*) as CountHasInsurance
 from
    Elites e
    group by e.HasInsurance
```

And the output obtained is equal to:

```
YES   ==>   3
```

But I want to get the following output :

```
YES   ==>   3
NO    ==>   0
```

I do not want to create a new table in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN`.  I would recommend:

```
select v.hasInsuranceStr, count(e.hasInsurance) as CountHasInsurance
from (values (N'Yes', 'true'), (N'No', 'false')
     ) v(hasInsuranceStr, hasInsurance) left join
     Elites e
     on e.hasInsurance = v.hasInsurance
group by v.hasInsuranceStr;
```

Some notes:

- This does not use the name `hasInsurance` for the first column.  That is already an integer value.  I recommend a different name.
- The `VALUES()` has both the number and the lookup value.
- Presumably `true` represents a string, because SQL Server does not support boolean types.

Comment: *"because SQL Server does not support boolean types"* Not true. A `bit` can easily be used as a Boolean value and supports the values `'true'`/`'false'`: `SELECT CONVERT(bit, 'true'), CONVERT(bit,'false');` returns `1` and `0` respectively. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d20d582d5ee42afab3ea03024a5c4d73) (*Interestingly, DB Fiddle actually displays `True`/`False`, so I have use `bit` values too to demonstrate*)

Comment: @Gordon , After writing the `where` command before the `group by` command, the NULL group is deleted. **`Where ==> e.IsEnable = 1 `**

Comment: @Larnu . . . `true` and `false` (unquoted) are not valid values in SQL Server.  For instance:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e3ac9e1a9177eb4cae85c330dde9be78.

Comment: @Larnu  `'true'` and `'false'` are strings that are implicitly converted to bit _in certain contexts_. This is a far cry from fully supported, official boolean types.

Comment: Wouldn't you just suggest that is a dialect difference though @AaronBertrand ? Unless you're suggesting that a Boolean has other functionality that a `bit` does not; if so what is missing? I wouldn't suggest that only the need to quote `true`/`false` counts as "not supported" when dealing with `bit`;  would be like stating string concatenation isn't supported on T-SQL because it uses a `+` operator instead of a `|` (if that is your only reason for stating it isn't supported). If you are suggesting `bit` can't be used for a Boolean either, what are you suggesting should be?

Comment: @Larnu depends on how pure you want to be. Many feel that a true Boolean does not allow null. The point Gordon was making, though, at least I think, was specifically that the unquoted `true` and `false` are not magical keywords for `bit` the way you would expect for a proper Boolean type (whether or not it allows three-valued logic).

Comment: @Larnu the differences are subtle but not worthy of extended debate. If you want to get to the simplest form, you can't say `DECLARE @IsEnabled boolean;` therefore SQL Server does not have a boolean type. While `bit` comes close, again *for some people*, it wasn't named `boolean`.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand, appreciate the responses.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . The biggest difference is that you cannot say `where @IsEnabled` or `(case when @IsEnabled then . . . end)`.  Bits are not booleans.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you what you're after:

```
SELECT TF.[value] AS HasInsurance,
       COUNT(E.HasInsurance) AS [Count]
FROM (VALUES('True'),('False')) TF([Value])
     LEFT JOIN Elites E ON TF.[value] = E.HasInsurance
GROUP BY TF.[value];
```

A query won't return rows for data that doesn't exist; the `VALUES` clause therefore creates rows for both `'True'` and `'False'`, meaning that values can be returned even if they aren't in the `Elites` table.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
Select 
  CASE WHEN e.HasInsurance=1 THEN N'YES'  ELSE N'NO' END AS HasInsurance, 
  COUNT(e.HasInsurance) as CountHasInsurance
FROM (SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1) AS s(x)
LEFT JOIN Elites e
   ON s.x = e.HasInsurance
group by s.x
```